# Zooming a UIScroolView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, quartz-2d

I have a Storyboard with a Scrollview with Myview class extended from UIScrollview which implements a method to paint some rects with quartz2d.

I'm trying to implement zoom in/out in that Scrollview but theres no way and I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have this in my controller (UIwindow):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[myscrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myscrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
myscrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;
myscrollview.minimumZoomScale= 1.0;
myscrollview.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
[myscrollview setZoomScale:myscrollview.minimumZoomScale];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   return myscrollview;
}
```

But it doesnt work. Where can I find some information about implement zoomin/out in iOS 5.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try after setting delegate

```
 myscrollview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Assigning 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'MyWindow *const__strong'

Comment: Yes, it is. Should I ignore it?

Comment: change your interface as @interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> it wiil fix the warning

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set your delegate like this: `myscrollview.delegate = self;`

In your `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate method you have to return a view you like to zoom an not the scrollview itself.

Comment: I want the same view, zoomed, How can I do that? I have a black background with red lines drawn with:

        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        
        CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        
        CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
        CGContextBeginPath(c);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(c, x*12, y*10);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, x+10, y+10);

Comment: move the drawing to a separate view you can not scale the scrollview itself.

Comment: Something like

     UIView* myview;
     [myview drawlines]
     myscrollview = myview

??